# Preserving hostname on HATEOAS Resource with OpenFeign

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to add a URI to a resource located in a different microservice using OpenFeign and a ResourceAssembler, while preserving the hostname from the original request.

When making a REST request to a HATEOAS resource in another microservice, the resource.getId() method returns a link where the hostname is the Docker container hash instead of the original hostname used to make the request.

### Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bulletins")
public class BulletinController {
// Autowired dependencies

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<BulletinResource>> getBulletins(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinRepository.findAll(pageable);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(pagedResourceAssembler.toResource(bulletins, bulletinResourceAssembler));
    }
}
```

### Assembler

```java
@Component
public class BulletinResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<Bulletin, BulletinResource> {
    private final AdministrationService administrationService;

    @Autowired
    public BulletinResourceAssembler(AdministrationService administrationService) {
        super(BulletinController.class, BulletinResource.class);
        this.administrationService = administrationService;
    }

    @Override
    public BulletinResource toResource(Bulletin entity) {
        Resource<Site> siteRessource = administrationService.getSiteBySiteCode(entity.getSiteCode());

        \\ Set other fields ...

        bulletinRessource.add(siteRessource.getId().withRel("site"));
        return bulletinRessource;
    }
}
```

### Feign Client

```java
@FeignClient(name = "${feign.administration.serviceId}", path = "/api")
public interface AdministrationService {

    @GetMapping(value = "/sites/{siteCode}")
    Resource<Site> getSiteBySiteCode(@PathVariable("siteCode") String siteCode);

}
```

### Bulletin Resource

```java
@Data
public class BulletinResource extends ResourceSupport {
// fields
}
```

Expected result
curl http://myhost/api/bulletins

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "bulletinResources" : [ {
      "entityId" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://myhost/api/bulletins/1"
        },
        "site" : {
          "href" : "http://myhost/api/sites/000"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  [...]
}
```

Actual result
curl http://myhost/api/bulletins

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "bulletinResources" : [ {
      "entityId" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://myhost/api/bulletins/1"
        },
        "site" : {
          "href" : "http://b4dc1a02586c:8080/api/sites/000"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  [...]
}
```

Notice the site href is b4dc1a02586c, which is the Docker container id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to manually define a RequestInterceptor for the FeignClient and manually add the X-Forwarded-Host header, as well as define a ForwardedHeaderFilter bean in the service the request was made to.

### Client Side

```java
public class ForwardHostRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    private static final String HOST_HEADER = "Host";
    private static final String X_FORWARDED_HOST = "X-Forwarded-Host";

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .getRequestAttributes();

        if (requestAttributes == null) {
            return;
        }

        HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
        String host = request.getHeader(X_FORWARDED_HOST);
        if (host == null) {
            host = request.getHeader(HOST_HEADER);
        }

        requestTemplate.header(X_FORWARDED_HOST, host);
    }

}
```

### Producer side

The producer side also required modification as per the discussion on
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/862
which refers to the following documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#server.link-builder.forwarded-headers
which states to add the following bean in order to use forward headers.

```java
@Bean
ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
}
```